# Crystal Report, Group based Summary at report footer

Tags: crystal-reports

HI,

Is it possible to display summary of a group at the report footer ? Let me explain the scenario. I've to create the following kind of report:

```
Client    Amount    Currency 

Customer 123:

WWWW       300         SGD
XXXX       400         SGD
YYYY       200         USD
ZZZZ       300         USD


Customer 456:

W1W1       300         SGD
X1X1       400         SGD
Y1Y1       200         USD
Z1Z1       300         USD

.
.
.
.
.
```

At the report footer, I need to show the following:

```
Grand total: USD        1000
Grand total: SGD        1400
```

Need to display grand total of amount by Currency at Report footer.Is it possible to do in Crystal report? I'm using crystal report version 11. Could anyone suggest me a solution ?

Comment: If the two grand total figures are all you need then a simple Running Total field will suffice! no?

Answer (score 3):

I think the only way to do this is to add a Sub Report to the footer.  Use the same query as the original report and then Group everything by Currency and sum the Amount.

Comment: Thanks. I thought of using a sub-report earlier, but looking for a simple solution within a report. Now i guess, we cannot make it without sub-report it seems.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative to Barry's solution, if you know what currencies you're dealing with in advance, you could simply use a running total field for each currencly,

In the Evaluate section click formula and enter something like this (for the USD currency for instance)

```
{YourTableOrCommand.currency} = "USD"
```

Type of Summary should be: **sum**
Reset should be: **Never**

This may give you a different performance characteristics then having a sub-report, but you'd need to test this.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry for not mentioning it in the question. Not dealing with particular currencies. Here Currency is a variable. Need to find grand total of all available currencies at report footer.

Comment: yesosuresh, based on your comment, this solution is the best option if you have a small number of currencies (Just make a new running total for each currency).  But if you're dealing with a large number of currencies, then Barry's solution is the way to go.

It's been over a month since you asked the question, but if you're reading this, please go ahead and green-check the solution you went with.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do it:

1. Create two formulas; return the amount value based on the currency type.

   iif(Currency = "SGD", Amount, 0)

   iif(Currency = "USD", Amount, 0)
2. Create a summary based on the above formula using `sum`