# Crystal Report Group Amount total in Report Foooter

Tags: crystal-reports

there is one company with 5 currency

```
EUR  
GBP  
PKR  
AED  
USD
```

I have inserted a group w.r.t currency and its showing currency total after each currency

I want to show each currency total in the report footer. I have tried to insert the summary of Balance amount with group of currency, but its only showing the total of last currency which is in my case USD.

Is there a way to post each currency total in the report footer like this

```
**PKR Total   Amount  
**EUR Total   Amount  
**AED Total   Amount  
**GBP Total   Amount  
**USD Total   Amount
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can

Create these 5 formulas

```
(if {Tablename with currency code} = "PKR" then  {table with Balance})  
(if {Tablename with currency code} = "USD" then  {table with Balance})  
(if {Tablename with currency code} = "GBP" then  {table with Balance})   
(if {Tablename with currency code} = "AED" then  {table with Balance})   
(if {Tablename with currency code} = "EUR" then  {table with Balance})
```

at the report footer take a summary of this formula

Answer (score 0):

You again just copy or insert summary of currency in report footer and that will work.

Just check this link.

[Crystal Report, Group based Summary at report footer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2987621/crystal-report-group-based-summary-at-report-footer)

http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?702297-Crystal-XI-Group-Summary-in-Report-footer

http://www.forumtopics.com/busobj/viewtopic.php?p=660582

http://arstechnica.com/civis/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=111265

Answer (score 0):

Easy way would be store the summaries in a array and display in report footer.

Follow below process:

Create a formula `@Concat` and place it in group footer after your summary.

```
Shared StringVar Store;

Store:=Store+ToText(Sum ({Tablename.currency}, {Tablename.currency})
```

This will add the currenct to the variable store.

Now create the as many formulas as your currency and write below code:

Formula `@1`

```
Shared StringVar Store;    // This will give you first value
Store[1]
```

In the same way create for all values as `Store[2] //for second value` and to the end and display in report footer